# Greek letters with Minted or listings and LuaLaTeX

Tags: listings, luatex, minted, input-encodings, greek

I am trying to get a listing into my LaTeX document.

A simple listing would be the following XML:

```
<!-- Lüscher-Weiß with β -->
```

Then I try to get this into my document.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\RequirePackage[charter, greekuppercase=italicized]{mathdesign}
\RequirePackage{berasans}
\RequirePackage{beramono}

\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{minted}

\newmintedfile[listingxml]{xml}{
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    style=bw,
    outencoding=utf8,
}

\begin{document}

\listingxml{listing.xml}

\end{document}
```

What I get is somewhat close, but not good:

[image]

There are two issues:

- The two hyphens are combined into an en-dash, which is not what I want.
- The literal UTF-8 “beta” is removed. At least the “ü” and the “ß” are there with `luainputenc`.

With `listings` instead of `minted` I get similar results:

[image]

`listingsutf8` package does the same.

Why is this literal “beta” missing? I thought that LuaLaTeX and everything with UTF-8 would *finally* free me from encoding problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `beramono` does not include Greek character support. Try a different font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lstset{%
  language=XML,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
With listings:
\begin{lstlisting}
<!-- Lüscher-Weiß with β -->
\end{lstlisting}
With minted:
\begin{minted}[fontfamily=tt]{XML}
<!-- Lüscher-Weiß with β -->
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it is an issue with the font!